# CentOS6:yumでMariaDBがインストールできない

Tags: centos, mariadb, yum

CentOS6.8にてDjangoを利用するために[こちら](http://qiita.com/taijijiji/items/8da746e150d1e0947107)を参考に環境構築したところ、MariaDBをyumでインストールしようとしたところ、パッケージが利用できない事象が発生。
venvで仮想環境を作成し、その環境上で実行しています。

```
(venv_app1) [vagrant@localhost django_apps]$ sudo yum install -y mariadb-server mariadb-devel
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror
インストール処理の設定をしています
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: www.ftp.ne.jp
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * extras: www.ftp.ne.jp
 * remi-safe: ca.mirror.babylon.network
 * updates: www.ftp.ne.jp
パッケージ mariadb-server は利用できません。
パッケージ mariadb-devel は利用できません。
エラー: 何もしません
(venv_app1) [vagrant@localhost django_apps]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
```

pythonのバージョン/シンボリックリンクは下記のようになっています。

```
(venv_app1) [vagrant@localhost django_apps]$ cd /usr/bin/
(venv_app1) [vagrant@localhost bin]$ ll | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root        28 12月  5 23:07 2016 pip -> /usr/local/python/bin/pip3.5
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root        29 12月  5 23:06 2016 python -> /usr/local/python/bin/python3
-rwxr-xr-x.   2 root root      4864  7月 24 05:23 2015 python.bk
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root         6  6月 10 02:31 2015 python2 -> python
-rwxr-xr-x.   2 root root      4864  7月 24 05:23 2015 python2.6
```

yumは下記のとおりです。

```
(venv_app1) [vagrant@localhost bin]$ cat /usr/bin/yum
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import sys
try:
    import yum
except ImportError:
    print >> sys.stderr, """\
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   %s

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
%s

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

""" % (sys.exc_value, sys.version)
    sys.exit(1)

sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/yum-cli')
try:
    import yummain
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
    print >> sys.stderr, "\n\nExiting on user cancel."
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: 該当環境のセットアップ経験が無いので具体的な手順はわかりかねるのですが、エラーとなる原因は、[CentOS6オフィシャルリポジトリ](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/)にはmariadbが登録されていないからでしょう
(参考にされているリンク先ではCentOS7を使用しており、[こちらには含まれている](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/))。
[MariaDBオフィシャルリポジトリ](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/yum/)から取得すれば解決するかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すでに指摘されていますが、 MariaDB のパッケージは CentOS 7 から標準リポジトリに登録されており、CentOS 6 以前ではそのままではパッケージ利用はできないようです。

yukihane さんの指摘通り、リポジトリを追加すると解決するかと思います。

https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=yamagata-university&distro=CentOS&distro_release=centos6-amd64--centos6&version=10.1

```
cat << "_EOF_" > /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos6-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
_EOF_
```